# What do I need to put inbetween 2 f connectors to extend it?

Tags: internet, modem, cable, coaxial

I asked a question for the cable and could only find this:

http://m.canadiantire.ca/mt/www.canadiantire.ca/AST/browse/7/Electronics/TVsAccessories/VideoRemotesAccessories/PRD~0452382P/RG6+Video+Coaxial+Cable%2C+50.jsp?locale=en&un_jtt_redirect#video

I didn't pick it up yet but it seems both ends of that require an input like in my cable modem. How can I secure it on the same cable that comes out of wall when it seems like they both have same endings?

Is there another piece that will go in between 2 f connectors?

Comment: Okay, you may want to reword your question, describe the original problem you're trying to solve, then say what you bought / got / did and then phrase the question you're hoping to answer.  The above is a jumble of stuff.

Comment: Actually this was already answered in your previous question, but I forgot to add your name in the comment.  Note that couplers are available in "normal" and "wide" bandwidths.  You should get the wide bandwidth (3 GHz) coupler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an F connector [coupler](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=f%20connector%20coupler).

Comment: Thanks I found this: http://m.futureshop.ca/defaultpage.aspx?lang=en#/catalog/productdetails.aspx?ajax=true&sku=80730124&lang=en-CA This doesn't say coupler but looks similar. Would it work?

Comment: Based on the description, it sounds like the same thing (for some reason the picture isn't showing up for me). Also, if you go to any local store that sells electronics, they'll probably have some in stock near the home theater section.